# Hash function to switch on a string

Tags: c++, hash

I am trying to get to work a switch on a string in C++, with the help of a hash. It became personal between me and this code, so I don't wanna give up and use an enum, even though I finally have only like 8 strings to put in switch cases.

Combining what I saw on other topics, I wrote this very simple and not so reliable function, but that is enough for what I want to do, as it's not professional.

My function :

```cpp
constexpr long hashstr (const string &str, int h=0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 55 : ( hashstr(str, h+1) *33) + (unsigned char)str[h];
}
```

I then call it in this very simple main function (for now), but it won't compile, telling me that the case is wrong (not a constant). I don't understand this issue, as for me the string taken in arg is a constant, plus the function returns a constant expression.

My main :

```cpp
int main (void) {

    string teststr;
    cout << "test string :::>  ";
    cin >> teststr;
    int tt = hashstr(teststr);
    cout << "res -->  " << tt << endl;

    switch ( hashstr(teststr) )
    {
    case hashstr("rosathefloridaturtle") :
        cout << "ROSA OK" << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        break;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hoping that some of you can tell me what I'm not doing right...

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Use [tag:c++] and ONE of [tag:c++11] [tag:c++14] and [tag:c++17]

Comment: And don't forget about the pigeonhole principle. "Why isn't `hashstr("rosathefloridaturtle")` a constant" is a valid question, but the code you will end up with is generally incorrect.

Comment: And don't describe the error message. Post the exact error message.

Comment: Your `hashstr` definition also shouldn't compile (at least it doesn't in gcc), because string indexing is not `constexpr`, so the second error is irrelevant.

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful. Consider using the `lh_strhash` provided in the openSSL library. Efficient, and minimizes collisions for string hashing (it's really good)

Comment: @Groo if `std::string` is `constexpr` (i.e. when using c++20) [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) is also `constexpr`

Comment: I played around with this for a while, until I realised that I couldn't do better than the other answers. But because of you I have wasted five minutes of my life typing `rosathefloridaturtle` at the prompt. I hope you're satisfied.

Comment: Taken notes of all the bad habits, I won't do it again I promise 

Comment: @TonyK  I am effectively very amused, and Rosa is for sure satisfied, the nasty creature she is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are using c++20 `std::string` is not `constexpr` so can't be used in `hashstr`.

The value returned is larger than is representable in `long`, as signed arithmetic overflow is undefined behaviour your code can't be used in `constexpr`.

Fixing these two issues gives the working code:

```
constexpr unsigned long hashstr (const std::string_view &str, int h=0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 55 : ( hashstr(str, h+1) *33) + (unsigned char)(str[h]);
}
```

Note that if you look at the compiler output it probably tells you why your expression isn't `constexpr`, e.g. clang prints:

```
error: case value is not a constant expression
    case hashstr("rosathefloridaturtle") :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:18: note: non-literal type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>') cannot be used in a constant expression
    case hashstr("rosathefloridaturtle") :
```

Changing to `std::string_view` prints:

```
error: case value is not a constant expression
    case hashstr("rosathefloridaturtle") :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:47: note: value 97009635813568987014 is outside the range of representable values of type 'long'
    return !str[h] ? 55 : ( hashstr(str, h+1) *33) + (unsigned char)str[h];
                                              ^
<source>:9:29: note: in call to 'hashstr("rosathefloridaturtle", 8)'
    return !str[h] ? 55 : ( hashstr(str, h+1) *33) + (unsigned char)str[h];
```

Comment: Why are you using `const std::string_view&`?

Comment: @PasserBy no particular harm in it, just copied from the OPs code. probably still cheaper to recursively pass the reference than copying the string view even though a string_view  should be cheap to copy

Comment: Suppose the recursion isn't optimized out, given that it's a trivial type, passing by value will be done in registers, while references must be passed on the stack. I'm guessing both will be noops and pass by value saves an eventual indirection. But none of that really matters, a `string_view&` just reads like `int*&`, which is plain weird.

Comment: using the reference causes clang to generate less code with optimisations disabled: https://godbolt.org/z/5Ed93a

Comment: The [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/m4w8yzz1fpdKtmD9ga0_a22WekE). And I just realized why it's so wonky: we're passing an extraneous `h`. Also, using addition as a hash is a horrendously bad idea. Without the `h`, the [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/robkUgJ2e7SgXDoNwmKurOX3lmM) by value looks much better.

Comment: Well yes, your modified code is making new objects which does make passing by reference pointless

Answer (score 2):

As what **@Alan Birtles** said, `std::string` is not a `constexpr` based on the compiler standard you currently use, thus you cannot use like this.

But one good news is that you don't need to use `std::string_view` !, you just need to use `std::string::c_str()` and use the char pointer to get the hash value.

Also, based on the demand, I think you may want to use a technique called **natural overflow** which is widely used in hash(actually, it's a modulo function, but remove modulo operator which also stands modulo MAX_VALUE), but the type it uses is **unsigned** integer, and as what's mentioned by Alan, signed overflow may trigger a ub. So use an unsigned type instead.

Here's a code I implemented for this usage.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

using ull = uint64_t;

constexpr ull hashstr(const char* s, size_t index = 0) {
    return s + index == nullptr || s[index] == '\0' ? 55 : hashstr(s, index + 1) * 33 + (unsigned char)(s[index]);
}

constexpr const char* a = "rosathefloridaturtle";

int main() {
    string s;
    cout << "test string :::>  ";
    cin >> s;
    ull tt = hashstr(s.c_str());
    cout << "res -->  " << tt << endl;
    switch (tt) {
        case hashstr(a):
            cout << "ROSA OK" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```