How to use a full name in switch statement for readabilty?
I am still new to C++ and currently reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principles and Practice using C++".
As an exercise, I am writing a lexer and parser for a terminal calculator. The parser determines the kind of a single character in a string representing an expression, and assigns some kind-value to the token.
Beneath is a snippet of the function determining the kind (I did not include the entire function, or all cases, to make the code shorter):
switch(c)
    {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': 
        case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9': case '.':
            return 'n'; // 'n' for number
        
        case '*': case '/':
            return 'm';     // m for multiplication or division

        case '(': case ')':
            return 'p'; // p for parenthesis

        case ' ':   // whitespace
            return 'w';
        
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid token: A non-valid character was passed to determineKind");
    }

The reason I use chars to represent token kinds is because I can then use simple switch statements later, as opposed to less readable if statements with strings representing the kinds.
But, at the same time, 'n', 'm', 'p' and 'w' are magic constants, which makes the code inside the parser less readable again.
Is there a way I can use switch statements with full names like "number", "whitespace" and "parenthesis" to make everything simpler?

The better exercise would be to learn about the right tools for building such a thing -- flex / bison for the traditional approach, Boost.Spirit for the C++ way to do it...

This is a prime usecase for an enum or better yet enum class:
enum class TokenType
{
    Number,
    Multiplication,
    Parenthesis,
    Whitespace
};

TokenType parse(char c)
{
   switch(c)
    {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': 
        case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9': case '.':
            return TokenType::Number;
        
        case '*': case '/':
            return TokenType::Multiplication;

        case '(': case ')':
            return TokenType::Parenthesis;

        case ' ':
            return TokenType::Whitespace;
        
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid token: A non-valid character was passed to determineKind");

    }
}


Normally, you'd use an enum:
enum class Token
{
   Invalid=0,
   Number,
   Whitespace,
   Parenthesis
};

That way, you get a new type Token which can have values such as Token::Number.

If the OP is fond of the specific values, enum class Token : char { Invalid = 0, Number = 'n', Multiplication = 'm', Whitespace = 'w', Parenthesis = 'p' };

As others have said, enum should be the way to go for your use case. But you can use a hash function to use strings inside a switch statement. The hash function will create a unique integer from your input string which you then can use inside a switch case statement.
for example:
constexpr unsigned long hashstr (const std::string_view &str, int h=0)
{
    return !str[h] ? 55 : ( hashstr(str, h+1) *33) + (unsigned char)(str[h]);
}

taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196363/10825362
which can then be used like this
switch ( hashstr(inputstr) )
{
    case hashstr("examplestr") :
        break;
}


FYI: hashes are NOT unique...

@ChristianStieber well i am one of 10.000 today https://xkcd.com/1053/ ty
